# What does "Safe" mean in the Collections.toArray() JavaDoc?

Tags: java

When I read java source code, I found in the collection interface, will be safe

> The returned array will be "safe" in that no references to it are Maintained by this collection.(In other words, this method must allocate a new array even if this collection is backed by an array).The caller is thus free to modify the returned array.

I do not understand the meaning, can you provide an example for me?

Comment: What do you mean by safe ? Thread-safe ?

Comment: @Julien he probably means  ""safe" in that no references to it are Maintained by this collection."

Comment: @jbabey yes you are right i am sorry my english is pool thank you

Comment: @Julien hi As I read the source code, see the notes written on will be safe, so I did not understand

Answer (score 14):

Sure:

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("foo", "bar", "baz");
String[] array = list.toArray(new String[0]);
array[0] = "qux";
System.out.println(list.get(0));  // still "foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

This "safe" is not "absolutely safe".

If you modify the element's fields, the list will change with the array which is returned by `toArray()` . But if you point it to another reference, the list will not change with the array.

The reason is that `toArray()` returns an array that holds the memory address of the object.

**Change the element's content**

```java
ArrayList<Student> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Student("Sarah",17));
Student[] s = a.toArray(new Student[0]);
s[0].setName("Lily");
System.out.println(a.get(0)==s[0]);//true
```

**change the reference**

This is the "safe" that the source code annotates.

```java
ArrayList<Student> a = new ArrayList<>();
a.add(new Student("Sarah",17));
Student[] s = a.toArray(new Student[0]);
s[0]=new Student("Lily",20);
System.out.println(a.get(0)==s[0]);//false
```